# Sampling internediate points from x-y discrete mapping itself in Matlab

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I have plotted a piece-wise defined continuous linear function comprising of several oblique straight lines joined end-to-end:-

```
x=[0,1/4,1/2,3/4,1];
oo=[1.23 2.31 1.34 5.69 7] % edit
y=[oo(1),oo(2),oo(3),oo(4),oo(5)];
plot(x,y,'g--')
```

I now wish to sample points from this plot itself, say i want the `y` corresponding to `x=0.89`. How to achieve that using Matlab? Is there a special function in-built in Matlab?

Comment: can you show what `oo` looks like?

Comment: Check `interp1`. What do you mean by "from this plot itself"? You interpolate from `x` and `y`

Comment: @LuisMendo i should rather have said "from `x` and corresponding `y` arrays itself."

Comment: Then [`interp1`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/interp1.html) probably does what you want

Comment: @Benoit_11 `oo` just contains the mapping of elements in `x` to the `y` axis. I made an edit. So `oo` can be pretty much any numeral mapping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there's a built-in function for that: [`interp1`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/interp1.html):

> `vq = interp1(x,v,xq)` returns interpolated values of a 1-D function at specific query points using linear interpolation. Vector `x` contains the sample points, and `v` contains the corresponding values, `v(x)`. Vector `xq` contains the coordinates of the query points.
>   [...]

See the linked documentation for *further options*. For example, you can specify the *interpolation method* (default is linear), or whether you want to *extrapolate* (i.e. allow for `xq` values to lie outside the original `x` range).

Comment: So if i want the `y` corresponding to 0.89, then i type in: `y=interp1(x,y,0.89)`, right?

Comment: Yes, that's correct (except you may not want to overwrite `y`). You can also specify the interpolation method. Default is linear. check the doc for others. And there's an extra input argument to specify wether you want to extrapolate (i.e. outside the original `x` range)